# What is fatal error C1090: PDB API call failed, error code '3': vc142.pdb?

Tags: visual-studio

I set up a new project with Visual Studio 2019 version 16.3.10. When I try to build I get the following error:

EasyTcpStubs.c : fatal error C1090: PDB API call failed, error code '3': 
   W:\Dropbox\Me (Mine)\TcpToNamedPipe\TcpToNamedPipe\Debug\vc142.pdb

I have searched the internet and this site for any explanation of this error. Maybe I missed it but I could not find anything.
The project is a Console project.
The error occurs without a line number so it does not seem to be the source. I tried another project and it compiles OK (but it is an old project whereas this error is occuring on a brand new project.

Does anyone know something about this?

Comment: There was a ticket raised for this issue. It got resolved in the release 16.5.5.

Comment: The issue can still happen with VS2022 (17.6.4) for certain projects. According to comments it may be caused by simultaneous access to the same .PDB-file by multiple programs (antivirus, cloud client, etc.). I would blame TortoiseGit in my case, because generated .PDB (along with .LIB) are under source control, since the built library is treated as a pre-built 3-rd party component (yeah, I know it's a bad practice).
See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/68168673/536172

Comment: The code shown in the error message is a Win32 error code (see `winerror.h`). For example we're seeing this frequently with code 32, i.e. `ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION`, which seems to be related to Defender ATP (enterprise environment). It's a shame that any web search is doomed to find a gazillion irrelevant hits, because that code is just a very small piece of data and apparently not as important as C1090 by search engine standards.

Answer (score 5):

For me, I stopped Dropbox and it works. It seems that something is using W:\Dropbox\Me (Mine)\TcpToNamedPipe\TcpToNamedPipe\Debug.

Comment: I had the same issue and killing Dropbox solved the issue

Answer (score 4):

In my experience this error is likely due to some permission error. If your project is in Dropbox, OneDrive, etc, most likely you get this error because your Dropbox cannot sync and update files properly. Restart Dropbox and that should fix the issue.

Answer (score 3):

In My case, I suspect it is some type of race condition/lock issue with the code that opens/closes the *.pdb file.  In my case I am running /MP (Multiprocessor Compile) so up to 4 *.cpp modules being built at a time.  It works fine on a stand alone build machine.  But I'm a vendor and must use a VM environment to develop for my customer, and the disk requirements are so large I must place the builds on a network share.
The latency of file I/O access over a network share seems to be the issue.
Thats all I know about the issue at the moment.
As I learn/test discover more, I can improve this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Synology Drive Client (v3.2.0) caused this error for me. Pausing the sync eliminated the error. Thanks to all for the clue of DropBox, OneDrive, etc. causing the issue.

Comment: Yup - same - I just disabled it and voila - all fixed!