# Visual Studios repeatedly has a PDB API call fail while building project

Tags: windows, visual-studio

so I have a project that was housed in another directory that I copyied and moved into another directory in order to dump it into a local git repo that was previously running an earlier version of the code( I know why am I doing this copying stuff well it is a long story and irrelevant). after attmepting to build the project in visual studios 2019 I get the following error during the build.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C1090   PDB API call failed, error code '3': C:\Users\chad.lahue\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\TOC\project\TOC\Debug_sim\vc142.pdb TOC C:\Users\chad.lahue\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\TOC\project\TOC\TOC.cpp  1
```

so after looking up what causes this issue and trying the reboot sugestion to no avail or killing a second msbuild.exe process I have noticed in the task menu that about halfway through the build a second msbuild.exe comes up when building this project and does not on any project that builds successfully
[image]

Also the code is the same as well as the project settings as far as I can see from the original directory that it was copied from which still builds just fine.

My question is : 1 is this a code issue / project settings issue or is there some kind of directory or computer glitch?

: 2 has anyone else experienced this type of compiler error and had to resolve it in a more complicated way than what is normally suggested for this error ie. restart computer or kill the second msbuild.exe ? better yet has anyone ever had a project that generates 2 msbuild.exe's during the build process which causes it to fail as it appears to be here?

for others experiencing this issue despite updating their vs like I did the following project settings fixed the issue for me, I have also tried the /FS solution on another project that started experiencing the same issue

For those getting the issue with vc142.pdb try setting "Configuration Properties->C/C++->Output Files->Program Database File Name" to "$(TEMP)vc$(PlatformToolsetVersion).pdb"

It could also work for the other pdb's by setting "Configuration Properties->Linker->Debugger->Generate Program Database File" to "$(TEMP)$(TargetName).pdb".

My best guess is the files are being locked by mspdbsrv.exe due to parallel compilation.

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/fatal-error-c1090-pdb-api-call-failed-error-code-3/552999

Comment: for others experiencing this issue despite updating their vs like I did the following project settings fixed the issue for me, I have also tried the /FS solution on another project that started experiencing the same issues

Comment: @HansPassant They fixed it , then the broke it again in VS2019 this summer.  No real fix until VS2022 for now.  https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/VS2019-2019-16104-no-longer-passes-FS/1482274

Answer (score 1):

for others experiencing this issue despite updating their vs like I did the following project settings fixed the issue for me, I have also tried the /FS solution on another project that started experiencing the same issue an it seemed to clear it up for good as well.

For those getting the issue with vc142.pdb try setting "Configuration Properties->C/C++->Output Files->Program Database File Name" to "$(TEMP)vc$(PlatformToolsetVersion).pdb"

It could also work for the other pdb's by setting "Configuration Properties->Linker->Debugger->Generate Program Database File" to "$(TEMP)$(TargetName).pdb".

My best guess is the files are being locked by mspdbsrv.exe due to parallel compilation.

Comment: settings solution credit goes to @Ben-Baker from another forum

Comment: Sadly that doesn't work for stuff one has no control how it builds. CMake stuff invoked from conan, etc.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem except during my CICD process.  I found that removing the pdb files from my repository caused the build process to function correctly since the pdbs would no longer be locked down by the build process.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).